# Convering UK DateTime to US DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

The current regional settings on my Windows XP machine are *English (United Kingdom)*.
Using my C# app, how do I convert a `DateTime` object having value of 31/05/2012 to a US `DateTime` object ie. 05/31/2012?
Is this possible without setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the timezone offset matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateTime` values don't *have* a culture - they don't know anything about formatting themselves. You specify culture information when you parse and format them. It's not clear where you're getting your value from, but to *format* it with the US culture, you'd just use something like:

```
CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
string text = dateTime.ToString("d", us); // d=short date format
```

Note that you should only perform this formatting when you have to display the information to the user - keep the value as a `DateTime` for as long as you can. For example, if you need to insert it into a database, use it as a parameter value in a parameterized SQL statement rather than including a text representation within the SQL itself.

Comment: Thanks John.I need DateTime object to pass to another method.I tried following, but the usDateTime still contains date as : "29/06/2012" instead of "06/29/2012": DateTime ukDate = DateTime.Parse("29/06/2012"); CultureInfo us1 = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"); string text = ukDate.ToString("d", us1); // d=short date format DateTime usDate = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "d", us1, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

Comment: @Jimmy: No it doesn't. It doesn't contain a string representation *at all*. You're presumably just looking in the debugger - which will convert it to a string using your default culture. Ignore that format - the `DateTime` value has no inherent format. It really, really doesn't. Look at `text` instead of `us1`.

Comment: Thanks Jon.As always, your answers are pretty insightful!!:-)I was all the while looking at the output in Debug mode in VS.Net. thinking that the solution isnt working!When I run the program,its working as expected.!

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime ukDateTimeFormat = DateTime.Parse("10/26/2009 06:47",      
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

From UK format to US format, use following code snippet

```
DateTime usDateTimeFormat = DateTime.Parse("26/10/2009 06:47", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"));
```

Comment: Am I reading your answer correclty, does the second example convert form UK to US format? Because you use `en-gb` suggesting you're converting from US to UK

Answer (score 0):

Use cultures.

See here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx

Comment: -1: Answers shouldn't just be links to documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful.`

Comment: @Brendan Yeah but in this case its kind of like telling someone "you need to use programming". Also the linked article suggests changing the current culture of the thread, which isn't the best way to do this (and in fact the poster explicitly asks for a method that doesn't use this).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Justin.

Comment: In my defence, that snippet was added to the question after I posted my response.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string dtStringInUSFormat=dt.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

You need to import `System.Globalization` to access the `CultureInfo` class.